# Multiple resource files (.resx) for a single language

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using the Localizer at the moment to get the values for labels, buttons, etc. from a resource file.   This all works nicely using culture to pick which language resource file it should be using `LangaugeResource.en-GB.resx` being used correctly for British English and `LangaugeResource.cy.resx` being used for the Welsh translations.

Is there a way to add an additional layer to the localiser for the choosing of the resource file for example 
`LangaugeResource.en-GB.north.resx`
`LangaugeResource.en-GB.south.resx`
so that I can have two resource files, both for British English, but more localised or would I have to use some method other than localisation to use resource files like that?

Comment: I don't think so.  en-GB is tied directly to internationally recognized language key in the system.  en-GB.north is not.  You will have to engineer your own system for localization since this is your need.

Comment: Are resource files inextricably linked to localisation and language as all the links I can find don't mention one without the other?

Comment: I believe they are.  While I haven't seen any information contrary to that, I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is creating your own Culture based on another Culture.
For this you can use the [CultureAndRegionBuilderClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx) (create custom based on default en-GB). Afterwards your sample Resrouce.en-SB.resx should be used.

MSDN example:

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      // Create a custom culture for ru-US.
      CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder car1 = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("ru-US", 
                                             CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
      car1.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU"));
      car1.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo("en-US"));

      car1.CultureEnglishName = "Russian (United States)";
      car1.CultureNativeName = "русский (США)";
      car1.CurrencyNativeName = "Доллар (США)";
      car1.RegionNativeName = "США";

      // Register the culture.
      try {
         car1.Register();
      }    
      catch (InvalidOperationException) {
         // Swallow the exception: the culture already is registered.
      }

      // Use the custom culture.
      CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-US");
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
      Console.WriteLine("Current Culture: {0}", 
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
      Console.WriteLine("Writing System: {0}", 
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//     Current Culture: ru-US
//     Writing System: TextInfo - ru-US
```

Comment: Are resource files inextricably linked to localisation and language as all the links I can find don't mention one without the other?

Comment: You could load manually translations from resource files by specifying it exactly. But that would lead to an own implementation of resource loading class. The default localization (@Resource.<resourcekey> and selecting the correct resource file is tied together with the Culture - afaik

Comment: @Dave please be so kind to select my answer as solution if it was helpful for you.